# Problem with Load More Button in laravel 6 and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

so i have a problem in my laravel application when i access to the route where i posted the json i get the 500 error so there is the source :
the route :

**web.php**

```
Route::get('loadmore', 'MoviesController@loadmore');
```

**The controller :**

```
public function loadmore(Request $request)
{
    $movies_list = new Movies;
    if ($request->has('page')) {
        $movies_list = Movies::where('status', 1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(4);
    }

    $returnHTML = view('pages.ajax_movie', compact('movies_list'))->render();

    return response()->json([
        'html'         => $returnHTML,
        'page'         => $movies_list->currentPage(),
        'hasMorePages' => $movies_list->hasMorePages(),
    ])
}
```

**and finally the view :
location : pages/ajax_movies.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($movies_list as $movies_data)
     <a href="{{ URL::to('movies/'.$movies_data->video_slug.'/'.$movies_data->id) }}" class="movie">
      <span class="r"><i class="i-fav rating"><i>{{$movies_data->imdb_rating}}</i></i></span> 
       <img src="{{URL::to('upload/source/'.$movies_data->video_image_thumb)}}" alt="" title=""> 
        <span class="title">{{$movies_data->video_title}}</span> 
        <span class="ribbon ">
        <span>{{$movies_data->video_access}}</span>
       </span> 
        </a>
        @endforeach
```

everyone can help me ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the ajax code?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (`;`) at the end of `response()->json(...)`. Please can you add the error you're getting in your network tab or your laravel.log.

Comment: thank you so much it work @Rwd